# How to handle Multiple Requests from Django App?

Tags: python, django, request

I have a requirement, where only one instance of the Django application is supposed to be running on a remote server.

The user will make a request to the service and the application will process batch data and return back output. In this particular scenario, I have been asked to handle multiple requests in a queue from inside the Django application which is slightly odd.

If I have to move forward with this approach, what would be the best way to implement the queue. Also if there is an option to use some kind of a queue outside the application, what would be the best and fastest approach for it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Django 3.1+ supports async views.
So inside an async view, you could make dozens of async requests, await the results, and send back a needed payload.
Docs: [Asynchronous support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/)